# Why do I get a bash: syntax error near unexpected token on every bit of code with VS Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, visual-studio-code

I am very new to coding, and have just installed VS Code, and installed Node.js as well as Git Bash. I was working on a project, but couldn't console.log anything as I always received the following error when using Git Bash:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `validateCred' (One of the
> variables I used)

I created a new JS file, and ran the following code:

```
const hello = 'hello world';
```

I still received the same bash error. I have tried replacing my code with code that I know works and still receive the same errors.I have also tried using Powershell as my terminal, but receive the following errors every time:

> batch : The term 'batch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again.

I am at a loss, and I'm sure it's something really simple, but I can't seem to figure it out!

Comment: What are you going with git bash? unclear how that relates to JavaScript/Node. Seems like you are taking a Spanish class, but the teacher is Talking in French. Using the wrong tool for the job??

Comment: I suspect a [shebang](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-shebang/) might help. `#! /bin/env node` or some such.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was trying to console.log to see the results of running my code, and assumed I would do this in Git Bash. Like I said, I’m a complete novice here, and was unsure how to actually run my code to see if the functions were returning what they should.

Answer (score 1):

A Bash shell expects you to enter Bash code and not JavaScript code.

If you want to run JavaScript code then you need to run it in Node.js and not in Bash.

Generally, the command `node` will launch Node.js in a Bash shell. (Assuming it is installed on the `$PATH`).